# cannot create materialised view through dbt core

Tags: dbt

I am currently using dbt for data transformation in PostgreSQL, but I am facing challenges in creating a materialized view using dbt-core. The installed version of dbt-core is 1.5.4. Could you please provide a solution for creating a materialized view using dbt-core?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the issue is by upgrading the dbt-core and adapter version greater than 1.6.